# Removing a key from nsmutableDictionary in ios

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` which is returned from a server in JSON format.

From that I have to remove one key which is null and not use. I have to remove both the key and the value

How can we remove that key....

The key values are

```
appointmentType = 1;
description = Right;
endDate = "2013-09-11";
endTime = "02:30:00";
flgHolidaySchedule = 1;
flgSiteSetupSchedule = 1;
therapistId = "maheswaran@excelgoodies.com";
uri = "<null>";
```

Now i have to remove uri Key from dictionary....

Comment: Come on, why not read [NSMutableDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the dictionary and look for any null entries and remove them.

```
NSMutableDictionary *prunedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString * key in [yourDictionary allKeys])
{
    if (![[yourDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        [prunedDictionary addObject:[yourDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

After that, prunedDictionary should have all non-null items in the original dictionary.

Comment: my requirement is not about removing null values....I have remove key from dictionary....if i print all keys  of dictionary the removed key is must not printted...

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code :

```
NSMutableDictionary *myTemDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString * key in [yourDictionaryFromJSON allKeys])
{
    if (![[yourDictionaryFromJSON objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        [myTemDictionary addObject:[yourDictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}

NSLog(@"%@", myTemDictionary); // check it in console your dictionary has not any NULL value
```

Comment: thanks....But my requirement is not about removing null values....I have remove key from dictionary....if i print all keys of dictionary the removed key is must not be printed...

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple:

```
[yourDictionaryFromJSON removeObjectForKey:@"uri"];
```

Comment: my requirement is not about removing null values....I have remove key from dictionary....if i print all keys of dictionary the removed key is must not printted...